# Identity between Euler gamma and pi

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

Let $\gamma$ be Euler constant and $W$ Lambert W function.

One can show:

$$-2/3\,{\frac {\gamma+\ln  \left( \pi  \right) }{W \left( 
-1/3\,{\frac { \left( \gamma+\ln  \left( \pi  \right)  \right) {
{\rm e}^{-1/3\,\gamma}}}{\sqrt [3]{\pi }}} \right) }} = 2 \qquad (1) $$

This means at least one of $  \left( 
-1/3\,{\frac { \left( \gamma+\ln  \left( \pi  \right)  \right) {
{\rm e}^{-1/3\,\gamma}}}{\sqrt [3]{\pi }}} \right)$ and
$\gamma+\ln  \left( \pi  \right)$ is transcendental.

> Q1 Is this known?
>
> Q2 Can one solve (1) for $\gamma$ or $\pi$? (sage, maple and
>   Wolfram Alpha couldn't).

In machine readable form:

```
 def eulerpi():
      import mpmath
      from mpmath import lambertw,euler,pi,log,exp
      mpmath.mp.dps=10**4
      a= -2*(euler + log(pi))/lambertw(-1/3*( (euler+log(pi))*exp(-euler/3))/pi**(1/3))/3-2
      print mpmath.chop(a)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the definition of the Lambert function 
$W\left(-\frac13\alpha e^{-\alpha/3}\right)=-\frac\alpha3\,$ for any $\alpha$, so 
$$
-2/3\frac\alpha{W\left(-\frac13\alpha e^{-\alpha/3}\right)}=2.
$$
Putting here $\alpha=\gamma+\ln\pi$ gives your formula.

Comment: I don't get numerical support for your second formula for alpha=4 and alpha=5, in both sage and Maple. Is it a CAS bug? (Though it works for gamma + log(pi))

Comment: @joro for some intervals the Lambert function is multiwalued http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function. May be the program computes another branch.

Comment: Btw, I tried to check if the stupid question is  a trivial tautology, but branches of $W$ fooled me.